# Is it possible to print from a tablet to a label printer?

Tags: tablet, label-printer

Is it possible to print from a tablet (or a smartphone) to a label printer? The keyword here is mobile. I need to print nametags for people attending an event. As they arrive I want to print their nametags. I would like to go to my website, select the person from the list of attendees and print his or her name on a label.

(Right now we're printing 300 to 400 labels per event but 50% never shows up. I want to print from a list as they arrive. Advantage: no more waste. Disadvantage: I have to haul a tablet and a label printer around.)

Comment: please tell us what kind of label printer

Comment: Simplest and cheapest solution is to pre-print the tag info with a laser printer on sheets of labels or detachable cards and toss what doesn't get used.  The media is cheaper and it takes much less prep time.  Even discarding half, the media cost is likely to be lower, and you don't need to haul anything or spend time preparing and printing them one at a time.

Comment: @sav : any label printer. I don't have one yet, I'll have to buy one so I'm open for anything!

Comment: @fixer1234 : yes, you may be right, but I hate waste, especially paper. I guess the older I get, the greener I get.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are some companies that offer wireless label printers, e.g. `Brother QL-710W` and `Brother QL-720NW` (with iOS devices): [Brother™ iPrint&Label](http://www.brother-usa.com/downloads/iphone-ipod-label-printing.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There's [visual ZPL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vzpl/)

uses the ZPL printer language.

The label printers that I am familiar with have used ZPL. It is possible to print to label printers from a tablet as I have written applications that do just that. They usually send print jobs using the ZPL language. But you can use visual ZPL to do that.

Comment: http://www.printersupermarket.com.au/Products/LaserPrinters/Zebra110XI44IN600dpiThermalTransferPrinter.aspx?gclid=CPy3wc-_y8sCFQF_vQodXhoD-g

Comment: But then you need an additional app... Ideally I would print from a web page (or the web page can create a PDF and then print the PDF).

Comment: Do you know of any label printers that prefer pdf?

Comment: I remember working with the DYMO, they are relatively cheap. And it looks like there are some javascript libraries for printing to them if you are prepared to write code. http://developers.dymo.com/2010/06/02/dymo-label-framework-javascript-library-samples-print-a-label/